# ordered data in django chartit

Tags: django

I am using [django-chartit](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/demo/pivot/simple/) to display a site name on x-axis and its response time on y-axis.

How do I sort the graph with the response time in ascending order. I am using order_by in the queryset but still its not ordering correctly.

Below is my code :

```
    siteresppivotdata = PivotDataPool(
        series =
            [{'options': {
            'source': MonthlySiteResponse.objects.all(),
            'categories': ['site_name', ],
            'legend_by' : ['site_name'],
             },
              'terms': {
                  'total_response_time': Avg('response_time')}}
             ],
             pareto_term = 'total_response_time' ## Added this code for sorting
         )

    #Step 2: Create the PivotChart object
    siteresppivcht = PivotChart(
            datasource = siteresppivotdata,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{

                  'type': 'bar',       ## Show response_time on x-axis and site_name on y-axis with the 'bar' i.e (reverse of the column graph)

                  'stacking': True},
                'terms':[
                  'total_response_time']}],
               chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Monthly Site Response Time'},
               'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Website'}},
               'yAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Response Time'}}}
            )
```

Also is there a way to show the graph vice-versa (i.e site name on y-axis and response-time on x-axis)

Comment: I got the answer for ordering by adding the pareto_term field in the PivotDataPool. i.e pareto_term = 'total_response_time'.
Updated the code. But still looking into reversing the axis fileds to display the graphs.

Comment: I also solved my second query to reverse the axis by changing the chart type to 'bar' instead of 'column'.
Code updated. hope it helps :)